# Text on 'Restart Kernel' button in VSCode Jupyter is wrong - %jupyter.command...shorttitle%

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

The "Restart Kernel" button at the top of the Jupyter tool in VS Code used to be titled "Restart Kernel" (of course), but now it shows what appears to be a variable name: `%jupyter.command.jupyter.restartkernel.shorttitle%`. It still works when you click on it, though. Does anyone know why this is and how to change it back (or who to report this to)?

[image: Header of VS Code Jupyter extension]

- Jupyter Extension (Microsoft) v2023.8.1002501831
- Jupyter Keymap Extension (Microsoft) v1.1.2

VS Code version information:

```
Version: 1.82.0 (user setup)
Commit: 8b617bd08fd
Jupyter 9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314
Date: 2023-09-06T22:07:07.438Z
Electron: 25.8.0
ElectronBuildId: 23503258
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

Comment: Looks like [you posted this as an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/14304), yeah? You can delete this question then. (You reported it in the right place, to be clear. And for future reference, all I had to do was google `VSCode Jupyter report bug` to get to the issues page.)

Comment: Yes I downvoted. Sorry if I wasn't clear: Where you're seeing a variable name instead of the actual label, that's obviously a bug, so the answer to "why" is "it shouldn't be like that" and for "how to change it back", you should post a bug report, which you already did, plus, "Questions asking us to ... find ... [an] off-site resource" are [off-topic](/help/on-topic). So overall, it's not a useful question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Regarding the search, my deeper point is that it was easy to find (no offense; maybe you just didn't know what to look for). Another option is to go to the [official VSCode Marketplace page for the Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) and click the "Issues" link.

Answer (score 0):

The place to post is the [vscode-jupyter repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues), and [I posted  this there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/14304).

The solution is to uninstall the Jupyter Extension in VS Code and then reinstall.